# Kernel SMC::smcReadKeyAction error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, console

I just looked in the OS X Console, and noticed that there's a huge number of errors looking like this:

```
6/12/12 8:33:16.000 PM kernel: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR F1Mn kSMCBadArgumentError(0x89) fKeyHashTable=0x0xffffff800a715000
```

There's one almost exactly every 5 seconds. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on OS X 10.7.4 ?
Then an explanation and possible solution **might** be found here on CNet:

[Tackling SMC console errors after OS X 10.7.4 update](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57432796-263/tackling-smc-console-errors-after-os-x-10.7.4-update/)

"Might", because it didn't work for me - even after uninstalling iStat Menus v2.x, so it must be some other application(s) on my part that is causing this...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Uninstalling Fan Control fixed the problem for me.

Comment: btw, I reset the SMC controller after uninstalling. Perhaps you need to do that to make it work for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Try: http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Resetting-The-Smc-System-Management-Controller-On-Your-Mac.htm

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately it didn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 0):

On 10.7.5 uninstalling IStatMenus 4 solved it for me.