# Errorr kernel SMC::smcReadKeyAction in Console

Tags: imac, macos, console

I have OSX 10.9 Maverics on my iMac and I got this message (in Console) every few seconds:

```
kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR TH0P kSMCBadArgumentError(0x89) fKeyHashTable=0x0xffffff802af9b000
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I have the same situation Maverick 10.9 smcfancontrol and all fans work not sure why this is occurring.

Answer (score 6):

The culprit can be a fan controll program you may have previously installed.

To my knowledge there are two possible candidates (FanControl & smcFanControl but there may be more that have the same problem).

You can verify if you have them installed and eliminate if needed.

NOTE: this problem is similar but not equal to this one [Kernel SMC::smcReadKeyAction error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53567/kernel-smcsmcreadkeyaction-error) The other one is for another version of OSX.

---

Procedure to check & eliminate FanControl

Open terminal and search for FanControl:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i fan
0   145     1   0 Gio12am ??         3:58.07 /Library/StartupItems/FanControlDaemon/FanControlDaemon run
```

This tell you that you really have FanControlDaemon running as pid 145 as PidNumber

To eliminate it :

```
$ cd /Library/StartupItems/
$ sudo rm -Rf FanControlDaemon/
```

and then kill the daemon:

```
$ sudo kill PidNumber
```

WARNING: if you replicate this procedure replace PidNumber with the PID you get from ps -ef

This eliminate the messages for me.

---

Procedure to check & eliminate smcFanControl

I also try to run the current version of another fan controll utility called smcFanControl (version is 2.4) and it seem to not work in Maverics (no window) but it produce near the same message in Console:

```
15/11/13 14:19:35,000 kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR TC0F kSMCBadArgumentError(0x89) fKeyHashTable=0x0xffffff802af9b000
```

Note that for smcFanControl you got "ERROR TC0F" instead of "ERROR TH0P".

If you have this problem you can try to find and kill the process "smcFanControl" instead.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i fan
501 45716   254   0  2:44pm ??         0:00.38 /Users/dave/Downloads/firefox/smcfancontrol_2_4/smcFanControl.app/Contents/MacOS/smcFanControl
```

If you find it then kill the rogue process as explained before.

Answer (score -1):

I too have the same error and I am using smcFanControl 2.4 with Maverics. The fan control seems to work just fine. I tested all three fans and they all did what I programed them to do, so I am not sure what issues you were having with the program.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not really answer the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favourite and you will be notified of any new answers. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with a link to this question if it helps provide context.