# Is it possible to reserve exact amount of space for the indexing and virtual memory?

Tags: macos, mac, performance, virtual-memory

Is it possible to reserve exact amount of space for the indexing and virtual memory?

I have Macbook Air with 128 GB SDD (with OS X Yosemite). When I run out of memory (free space less than 1 GB) the computer slows down and even hangs up.

I suspect that this slow down is due to the impossibility of indexing to be written on the disk and due to a lack of space for the virtual memory.

Is it possible to single out a place to be used *only* for paging and indexing? For example, to reserve 10 GB for that purpose?

In Linux systems there is a /var folder where these kind of stuff are written. It can be  put on a separate partition and this way to reserve certain amount of space *only* for itself. Is it possible to do something like this on a Mac in regard to indexing and virtual memory? I would sacrifice 10-15GB for it, if is needed.

Comment: The slowness is due to swapping in and out, the only solution is more memory - what do you mean by indexing?

Comment: By indexing I mean that Spotlight indexes my files.

Comment: I have seen a thread that discuss simislar questions. I post them here for further reading and aaplying when I have time:

[Prevent automatic removal of the Spotlight index due to low disk space](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37321/prevent-automatic-removal-of-the-spotlight-index-due-to-low-disk-space?rq=1)

[How can I move virtual memory swap files to a different drive or partition?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-can-i-move-virtual-memory-swap-files-to-a-different-drive-or-partition?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

As SSDs age, it takes more and more work for them to store data.  This is only made worse by having less than 1GB of space available.  In my experience (with a 2010 Macbook Air, with the 250GB SSD), performance GREATLY improved when I had >10% free space.

Do what you can to give your computer some breathing room!  **Delete some files now!**

Here's a classic article on how SSDs work.  Probably TMI, but...
   http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/06/inside-the-ssd-revolution-how-solid-state-disks-really-work/

Comment: I am constantly deleting files. The problem is that when the computer hang up due to low memory, deleting files is very difficult. I need a solution that will prevent me from running low of space for the most important OS X _system tasks_. My idea is the operating system to reserve certain amount of space and to show me – the end user – only the amount of space that I can use for _my_ files.